# Homology of 4-manifold minus a small ball

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Let $X$ be a simply connected compact 4-manifold without boundary. We know that $H_4(X)=\mathbb Z$. Intuitively, I can see why removing a small (open) 4-ball $D^4$ would kill the top homology, but I'm having trouble proving it. I tried using excision and Mayer--Vietoris, but neither seemed very helpful. One source I found said that it is "because" $X'=X-D^4$ has boundary $\partial X'=S^3$, but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: A manifold, may or may not be orientable, with boundary is homotopy equivalent to a non-compact manifold without boundary by collar neighborhood theorem. Also, any non-compact manifold, irrespective of the orientability condition, has trivial top (singular) homology.

Comment: @User Ahhh thanks! I forgot $X$ was compact

Comment: @User What is the "top" homology? Note that dimension is not a homotopy invariant: $\mathbb R^n\simeq\mathbb R^0$.

Comment: @Yai0Phah: This is the standard terminology in algebraic topology: If $X$ is an $n$-dimensional topological space (say, an $n$-dimensional nonempty manifold), then $H_n(X)$ is called the top-dimensional homology of $X$ (or just top homology).